# Form is not showing properly

Tags: vb.net, winforms

using VB.Net

Code

```
 If e.Modifiers = Keys.Control And e.KeyCode = Keys.Enter Then
            If textbox1.Focus() = True Then
                frmList.sFormID = 54
                frmList.Show()
            ElseIf textbox2.Focus() = True Then
                frmList.sFormID = 55
                frmList.Show()
            End If
End If
```

When textbox1.focus() at that time i clicked Control + Enter key, the formid=55 is showing instead of formid=54.

What wrong with my code.

Need code help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

```
If e.Modifiers = Keys.Control And e.KeyCode = Keys.Enter Then
            If textbox1.Focused = True Then
                frmList.sFormID = 54
                frmList.Show()
            ElseIf textbox2.Focused = True Then
                frmList.sFormID = 55
                frmList.Show()
            End If
End If
```

Note that I changed the test condition to [check for control focus](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.focused.aspx). Your test condition is attempting to set focus to a text box but in failure, you are probably seeing a default value - e.g., the formid 55. Without seeing more of what frmList is, I'm really only guessing. Is this in an event method? If so, can you provide that code?